# Check if a value is present and store in a new array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this variable with a value

```
$name=GTX 980
```

And I have array that has

Arraynames

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => GTX 970 [price] => 123 ) [1] => ( [name] => GTX 980 [price] => 321 ))
```

Now I want to check if array has name that matches to $name and store in a different array I tried this code

```
for($i=0;i<=count($shophive);$i++){
    if(strpos($shophive,$trimmedName ) !== FALSE){
        $newshophive[$i]=[
        'name' =>$shophive[$i],
        'price' =>$shophive[$i],
        'link'=>$shophive[$i],
        'image'=>$shophive[$i]
        ];
    }
}
```

But it gives error

Function name must be a string...

Can anyone explain what is wrong and what could be a solution?

Comment: `$strpos` is a variable, `strpos` is a function.

Comment: OKAY NOW I NEED A NEW TEXTEDITOR FOR VISIBLE TEXTS!!!

Comment: be aware that the first element of your array is another array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below, simply checks to see if given `String` is contained in a given array. If it does, it adds the element containing that `String` into a new Array and finally returns the result...

```
<?php

    $arr = [
        ['name'=>'GTX 970', 'price'=>123],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>321],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>350],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>300],
        ['name'=>'ABC 980', 'price'=>305],
        ['name'=>'JHK 980', 'price'=>375],
        ['name'=>'LMN 105', 'price'=>250],
    ];

    var_dump( searchArrayTree($arr, 'GTX 980') );

    function searchArrayTree($array, $searchValue){
        $result     = [];

        foreach($array as $iKey=>$item){
            $searchKey  = array_search($searchValue, $item);
            if($searchKey){
                $result[] = $item; 
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }
```

The `var_dump()` above (which is also [demoed here](https://eval.in/622241)) produces:

```
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 321
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 350
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 300
```

Alternatively, use `regex` so that you can narrow your search within group of related words like GTX 980 and still all entries with GTX 980 will be matched as well:

```
<?php

    $arr = [
        ['name'=>'GTX 970', 'price'=>123],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>321],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>350],
        ['name'=>'GTX 980', 'price'=>300],
        ['name'=>'ABC 980', 'price'=>305],
        ['name'=>'JHK 980', 'price'=>375],
        ['name'=>'Le EVGA GTX 980',                 'price'=>250],
        ['name'=>'GIGABYTE GEFORCE GTX 980 W3. ',   'price'=>250],
    ];

    var_dump(searchArrayTree($arr, 'GTX 980'));
    function searchArrayTree($array, $searchTerm){
        $result     = [];

        foreach($array as $iKey=>$item){
            $itemPrice  = $item['price'];
            $itemName   = $item['name'];
            $searchKey  = preg_match("#" . preg_quote($searchTerm). "#", $itemName);
            if($searchKey){
                $result[] = $item;
            }

        }
        return $result;
    }
```

The result of the `var_dump`([demoed here](https://eval.in/622253)) would look like this:

```
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 321
      1 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 350
      2 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GTX 980' (length=7)
          'price' => int 300
      3 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'Le EVGA GTX 980' (length=15)
          'price' => int 250
      4 => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'GIGABYTE GEFORCE GTX 980 W3. ' (length=29)
          'price' => int 250
```

Comment: "Call to undefined function searchArrayTree() " gives me this error!

Comment: I tried the whole code. Shows error on my side.

Comment: @ArAdAliSoomro     Check the working code here: https://eval.in/622241

Comment: My bad! I use jEdit I messed up the code!

Comment: A bit of modification I want. That is name is like EVGA GTX 980 and GIGABYTE GEFORCE GTX 980 W3. then how am I gonna search string from middle?

Comment: @ArAdAliSoomro  Use `preg_match()` rather than `==`. The Post will be updated to reflect that...

Comment: preg_match($searchValue, $item); you saying?

Comment: @ArAdAliSoomro The Post has been updated and hopefully that was also taken care of using `preg_match()`....

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a native php function with a `$` infront of it. `$strpos`.

It is searching for a variable called `$strpos` and it tries to pass 2 variables.
But since there is no variable set for `$strpos` it returns `NULL` and you get that error.

Comment: needle is not a string or an integer... now this!

Comment: The error tells everything you need to debug it.

Comment: Vasil I have update the code! Still error